# iText not generating expected PDF format

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am working on PDF generation using iText, Below is the code snippet.

```
String template="";//content given below for more readability
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Test.pdf"));
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(k.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
```

My template looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>.col{padding:3px 20px 3px 20px}</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family:tahoma">
    <div style="background:rgb(230,230,230); padding:5px ;border:1px solid black;">
    <b style="color:rgb(51,153,255)">Sample header</b>
    <img style="float:right" height="25px" width= "80px" src="resources/images/itext.png" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <table border='0' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <tr>
    <td class="col">String 1</td>
    <td class="col">: 1234354545</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="col">String 2</td>
    <td class="col">: rere</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="col">String 3</td>
    <td class="col">: ureuiu</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="col">Date</td>
    <td class="col">: dfdfjkdjk</td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr/>
    <br />
    Contact us
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like the given image in browser

[image: expected pdf]

But in PDF i am getting something like this

[image: actual pdf]

I am not able to find how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ParseHtml12](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtml12) and the corresponding result: [test2015-11.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/test2015-11.pdf)

[image]

What is the difference with your result?

In your result, you are using `<br />` tags which result in new line operations that take into account the *leading*. When you start a new page, the leading is 0. The leading changes as soon as you have some normal paragraphs where a leading is defined for the first time.

In your case, the definition of the leading never happens, so you have to do it yourself. For instance:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
writer.setInitialLeading(12);
```

Now the value of the leading will result in empty lines of 12 user units when you use the `<br />` tag.

As for the alignment of the logo: I suggest that you put that logo in a two column table where the text is added to the first column and the logo to the second column.